# Move-SPSite: Cannot find an SPSite object with ID or Url

Tags: powershell, spsite, move

One of my sites has grown large, and I want to move it to a new Content DB.

I've created a new content db, ResearchDB, successfully added it to SharePoint (New-SPContentDatabase), and checked

```
Get-SPSite "http://intranet" | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select Title
```

to verify that my site, Research, is listed.

When I use

```
Move-SPSite "http://intranet/depts/research" -DestinationDatabase "ResearchDB"
```

I'm gettting

```
Move-SPSite : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url:  http://intranet/depts/research.
 At line:1 char:12
 + Move-SPSite <<<<  "http://intranet/depts/research" -DestinationDatabase "ResearchDB
 "
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...PCmdletMoveSite:SPCmdletMoveSite) [Move-SPSite], SPCmdletPipeBindException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMoveSite
```

Did a little research which said to verify that AAM is set with  `http://intranet` in default zone, which it was.

Comment: run get-spsite "http://intranet/depts/research" and what is output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the error, its looks like you are moving a subsite not a site collection. [Move-spsite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607915.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) only works with site collections and it Moves site collections from one content database to another.

for verification you can run get-spsite "intranet/depts/research" and see if it returns an error or site id.